# MQTT v1.0.2 Jar

Tags: java, jar, mqtt

I am looking to get org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.0.2.jar. At the moment I can only get the libraries via pom.xml and maven. This is fine but the system I need to put the JAR on can not use maven/eclipse repo. I looked through the directories and could not find a JAR in it.

Is there somewhere I can download the JAR directly ?

Answer: https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho/org/eclipse/paho/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3/1.0.2/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.0.2.jar

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>Eclipse Paho Repo</id>
        <url>https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.paho</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

Comment: If you want to answer you own question post the answer in answers section instead of adding it in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the answer just as I posted the question so it may help others:
https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho/org/eclipse/paho/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3/1.0.2/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.0.2.jar